# Short Day and Long Day

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to output certain hours for the four different time periods: British Summer Time, British Winter time, Short Day and Long Day. We get input files that are 4am to 4am the following day.

When it is BWT the xslt works perfect because the system that outputs the hours makes it 6am to 6am which is what I want. Which was from 28/10/2018-31/03/2019

However in BST the system outputs it as 5am to 5am which is incorrect. which started on the 31/03/2019 - 27/10/2020

In the Short day 6am to 5am is the output

In the Long day 6am to 7am is the output

The Short Day and Long day is easier to solve, however with the Summer time and winter problem I need to give a range of dates instead of just one.

Is there a way to put when the date is in each of the time periods output 6am to 6am?

Input file:

```
        <ValidityPeriod v="2019-01-03T04:00Z/2019-01-04T04:00Z" />
```

Comment: I know what British Summer Time is. I have no clue what "Short Day" and "Long Day" are. Anyway, XSLT 1.0 has no clue when summer time is in effect where. You need to supply this information yourself, if you want to base a calculation on that. And I am pretty sure the period from 04:00 until 04:00 lasts 24 hours unless there was a change in the clock **during the same night** which only happens twice a year. Also, in your input example the datetimes are designated as having no offset from the UTC - so there should be no need to adjust them in order to know the exact difference between them. .

Comment: "And I am pretty sure the period from 04:00 until 04:00 lasts 24 hours unless there was a change in the clock during the same night which only happens twice a year." The changes in the clock during the same night are called the short day and long day, it's more of a work term. How would I go about supplying this information myself as the XSLT 1.0 will not recognise dates will it?

Comment: You could keep a table of such dates in an external XML document or in the XSLT stylesheet itself.

Comment: Wouldn't involve me adding all 365 days manually then?

Comment: You've tagged this XSLT 1.0 - if that's really the case then you get no help from the system at all, you have to do all the work "by hand" - though you may be able to use the EXSLT date/time library. By contrast, if you were using Saxon then you might be able to take advantage of extensions like saxon:in-summer-time().

Comment: I have to use this for my job that's why

Comment: You only need one entry per year e.g. `<year start="2018-03-25T01:00:00" end="2018-10-28T02:00:00">2018</year>`.

Comment: how would i refer to that period of time though, if I was to say when x is in that designated range do this, if it's in another designated range do that.

Comment: <xsl:if test="./ValidityPeriod"> how would I be able to say if the validity period was in the aforementioned year do this